# How to set typed dataset column to Nullable<int>

Tags: c#, types, dataset

I have an application made in C# which contains a `Dataset`. I'm using strongly typed properties and in one of the columns, I support `NULL` value in the `Database`. The issue is that whenever I try to use the column with the typed property, I get a `StrongTypingException`, since my row has a `NULL` value where I'm looking at it.

I went to my `Dataset` settings, into the column, and I tried changing the property `NullValue` to `Null`, but I get an error (`Property value is not valid.`), probably since the column's datatype is `System.Int32` and not `Nullable<int>`.

How can I make my column of type `Nullable<int>` ?

Comment: How are you creating the Dataset? Can you please post that logic?

Comment: I create the dataset with visual studios wizad. I linked it directly to my database, and I'm using stored procedures to get my data (with `Fill` and `GetData` functions). All the code is generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the column as Nullable, I had to remove the Identity property on SQL. Once that was done, I could change the `NullValue` property to `NULL` and everything works as intended now.

Answer (score -1):

public int? PropertyName { get; set; }  -  the questionmark make the type nullable

Comment: I undestand that it makes it nullable, however I cannot do so in the dataset